# Encrypted folder with decryption through network on Windows 7

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I'm trying to figure out some way how to have an encrypted folder, which could be decrypted throught network. I have Windows 7 Professional, I've searched for some ways, tried Bitlocker but it works only for Windows 7 Enterprise. Truecrypt doesn't have this functionality. I'd like to ask if there are any other ways.

Comment: There isn't a solution.  EFS does not work on network shares.  You can't use Bitlocker.  You have decided that a Truecrypt container on a network share does not meet your requirements.  You have eliminated or are unable to use all of the solutions at your disposal.

Comment: I should clarify something.  Due to your limitations there isn't a solution.  If your shares are located on a Windows Server machine there are solutions.